# Remove shopping cart django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

how can I delete a user's shopping cart automatically after a certain time (for example, after a one day)?

```
my view:
   def remove_cart(request, id):
     url = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
     Cart.objects.get(id=id).delete()
     return redirect(url)

my models :

   class Cart(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    variant = models.ForeignKey(Variants, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    create = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all `Cart`s one day after creation with:

```
from django.utils.timezone import now
from datetime import timedelta

Cart.objects.filter(
    create__lte=now()-timedelta(days=1)
).delete()
```

You can define this in a [*custom django-admin command* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-management-commands/#module-django.core.management). You can work with *celery* or another queue mechanism to [schedule a *periodic task*](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/periodic-tasks.html).

You can also add an `updated` field to only remove elements in cas these are no longer edited 24 hours ago:

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    # …
    update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Then you delete the `Cart`s with:

```
from django.utils.timezone import now
from datetime import timedelta

Cart.objects.filter(
    update__lte=now()-timedelta(days=1)
).delete()
```

Comment: tnx men for help